# Charset encoding with javascript widget to php

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm creating a Javascript widget which is a button that redirects a query string to a php page in a popup. The page that will integrate the widget sends information to the Javascript widget first using this method:

```
<script src="http://api.mydomain.com/widget/widget.js?api_key=123&firstname=Veronica&lastname=Gällman" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The widget reads the strings submitted and then creates the popup/iframe and redirects to http://api.mydomain.com/widget/index.php?firstname=Veronica&lastname=Gällman

The problem occurs when the page that included the JS widget does NOT have `charset=utf-8`. The special characters will become question marks, or boxes.

My programmer wants me to do do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var search = 'api_key='+encodeURIComponent('1234')+
        '&firstname='+encodeURIComponent('Veronica')+
        '&lastname='+encodeURIComponent('Gällman')+
    document.write( search );
</script>
```

But I find this approach problematic for the person who wants to use the widget, and not elegant at all.

So finally, my question: Is there a better way to solve this?

The script should support pages which have `charset=utf-8` and `charset=iso-8859-1` on them.

My suggestions to him were these:

1. Force integrator to send `&charset=iso-8859-1` in the query string, if it is not utf-8, and then convert the ISO to UTF-8 in index.php
2. Use a library to detect the character encoding. If it is detected as ISO, convert it into UTF-8 in index.php

Do any of these sound reasonable? Is number 2 possible? Or is there a better solution to this?

Am I forced to tell my widget users to `urlencode` on their page?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect encoding using [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function and convert it with [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

By the way, can't you make a world a better place by forcing people to use UTF-8? :)

Comment: The question remains. What does the integrating website need to do, and is there a better solution?

Comment: Sorry I can't offer a solution. It's already 8 or 9 years since I started using UTF-8 only and nobody else in my country and in neighbour countries use other encodings (well, except ASCII, but that's not the case).

Answer (score 1):

As Donatas already mentioned, it's better to force people -especially on the web!- to use UTF8 for quite everything.

But in case you need to convert a UTF8 string to ISO-8859-1, try http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_decode ...

PS: Remember, that not all UTF8 characters can be represented in ISO-8859-1 notation!

Comment: The problem is not converting strings.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry for that. You might want to use the character set specified for the used website. It's possible through `document.characterSet`. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.characterSet for further information. Use `document.charset` for IE.